# Active federation C#,WCF,Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, active-directory

Scenario:

- I have a WCF service hosted in Azure
- It is accessed by thick clients from domain joined machines
- I need to get the AD alias of the user accessing the service
- I don't want to ask the user to enter their username\password in my application. It should use the current credentials to authenticate

What I've tried:

- Code samples online which return a GenericXmlSecurityToken. This cannot be serialized and passed to the WCF service

Whats the proper way to do this?

I believe its the client which should authenticate against AD, get a token and send that token to the WCF service which would extract the alias from it.

Is this correct?

Could someone help by providing some samples on how exactly to get, pass and authenticate the token?

I'm kind of lost since most samples seem to assume an intermediate level of understanding of WCF, or rely on WiF which is not valid for .Net4.5

Comment: Consider using ADFS, WS-Federation and SAML tokens. WIF is built-in in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

> "I believe its the client which should authenticate against AD, get a
>   token and send that token to the WCF service which would extract the
>   alias from it."

That's correct. If you cannot use ADFS for some reason, you can setup a custom STS and authenticate to the custom STS with windows credentials. Custom STS will generate a SAML token which the client will pass on to the WCF service on azure. Read the claims identity guide V2 at http://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/67606